# Display two TextViews from a Layout

Tags: android, layout, textview, xamarin, android-resources

In Xamarin, how can I display two objects (TextViews in this case) vertically that refer to the same Resource.Id?

Here is my Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewAutoLink"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="all">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my C# code:

```
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.AutoLinkTextView);
TextView Web = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.TextViewAutoLink);
Web.Text = "Test address of http://www.google.com";

TextView Web2 = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.TextViewAutoLink);
Web2.Text = "Test address of http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

The Web2 TextView is the only TextView that is being displayed.

Can I have some help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why you don't add another `TextView` in your layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "\n" between both texts. Like:

```
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.AutoLinkTextView);
TextView Web = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.TextViewAutoLink);
Web.Text = "Test address of http://www.google.com"+"\n"+"Test address of  
http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yuo can add two TextViews in your Layout.

Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewAutoLink1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="all">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewAutoLink2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="all">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Source code

```
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.AutoLinkTextView);
TextView Web = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.TextViewAutoLink1);
Web.Text = "Test address of http://www.google.com";

TextView Web2 = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.TextViewAutoLink2);
Web2.Text = "Test address of http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: If I add two TextViews to one Layout, and I do not wish to use one of the TextViews, how do I not display one of the TextView's without affecting the Layout?

Comment: @user22707 you can `setText` of your `textView` that not used to empty ("") or you can change visibility of that

Comment: You can set empty text setText(""), you can change visibility setVisibility(View.Gone) or you can remove View from layout yourLinearLayout.removeChildAt(0)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting same `TextView id` for two different TextView.
So when yousetting your text , it's overriding previous text.

So basically you need two different `TextView`.